# How do i publish my Java code to localhost using Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm very new to programming and i'm too lost.

I wrote a simple Java code on Eclipse (2 Classes) without any GUI and i want to access this simple Java App from any device in my LAN using a browser.
According to what i found on Google and Stack Overflow, Tomcat might help me.
Tomcat 7 didn't work on my Eclipse, so i'm using version 6 of it.

How can i make a GUI for my app?

And what do I need to be able to publish it using Tomcat?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks Everyone in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is an application server. It means that you can write an application and then deploy it to a server (for example Tomcat). Then this application will be accessible on the server by some URL (for example http://localhost:8080/AwesomeApplication).

It only makes sense for web applications that handle some requests. You can't deploy an application with GUI, or simple console application to Tomcat or any other app server.

In language of final file representing your app - it must be a WAR file.

Comment: my app is about asking couple of questions (i prefer the answers to be radio buttons) and saves the answers in a text file on my laptop... i can use it perfectly inside the eclipse, what do propose so everyone on my LAN can access and answer this questions too?

Comment: You can try using Java socket API. Possible architecture in your case may look like this:

1) The GUI application you have is just an interface for underlying data stored in physically other place.

2) Everything is stored on a server, that is another Java application running on your laptop

3) The GUI application communicates with a server to retrieve questions and finally send answers to the server.

4) Server stores the answers in a file

Comment: Very good info.. i'll look up for Java socket API and see how it works! Thank u!